# Using python selenium to upload an image in button tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image JPG to a web. There's a button tag to upload it, HTML is the following:
[image]

The code i've been trying is the following but does not work:

```
PHOTO_PATH = ("C:/Users/tip/Desktop/proyecto_registro_minedu/input" + '/' + '72466985.jpg').replace('/', '\\')

def select_element(driver, by, to_look, click = True):
    if click:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, to_look))).click()
    else:
        return WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, to_look)))


# uploading photo
photo = select_element(driver, By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Subir archivo']", click=False)
# driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';",photo)
# driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')",photo)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display: block')",photo)
photo.send_keys(PHOTO_PATH)
```

I've already check other stackoverflow questions, but can't manage to make it work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: shouldn't you click the button in order to choose the photo and then upload it?

Comment: The matter is that I have to do this thousand times, and Selenium does not control windows pop ups. Or do you have another way to do it programmatically?

Comment: You can use `pyautogui` to control the pop ups

Comment: Anyway what are trying to do with `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display: block')",photo)` and `photo.send_keys(PHOTO_PATH)`?

Comment: @soundwave that code is a comment, I was trying some things founded in other forums. And pyautogui might be the approach I will take since can't be done only with selenium.

Comment: ok give it a try and let me know

Comment: @soundwave Thanks, taking advantage of your kindness and in case you are an expert with pyautogui, I'm getting an error when trying to execute ``` pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:/Users/tip/Desktop/proyecto_registro_minedu/input') ``` and the error says ``` [Errno 13] Permission denied:  ```. Any suggest about it?

Comment: maybe you are running the code from a directory where you don't have read/write permissions ? or you don't have permission on the folder `proyecto_registro_minedu/input`

Answer (score 0):

If there is an `<input>` field on the page you can also use that to upload the image, for example:

```
input_elem = driver.find_element(BY.CSS_SELECTOR, "input")
input_elem.send_keys(PHOTO_PATH)
```

Comment: Most of the questions solved in stackoverflow are related to the input tag. In the HTML coede of my questions exists an button tag, not an input one.